# While trying to configure Mulesoft Anypoint studio with Anypoint platform it's giving error

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio

While trying to configure Mulesoft Anypoint studio with Anypoint platform its giving error

> :The url you are trying to hit doesn't exist, url:
>   https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/ java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   anypoint.mulesoft.com  and i'm unable to connect Anypoint platform

[image]

Comment: Strange, do you have a proxy configured?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and then I realized that I had a different port configured for work stuff.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections and make sure the Port is 8080 for HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

In Anypoint Studio Goto Windows->Preferences->General->NetworkConnections
Under this change Active Provider to Direct

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative method to configure :export RAML files to Anypoint studio from Design center of Anypoint platform and we can add those RAML files into Anypoint studio and this way we can configure files from Anypoint platform to Anypoint studio.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely URL configured in Anypoint is not correct. You need to change the URL to https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/ which will fix the issue.